# What is the subject of "venit" in this sentence from Naufragium?

Tags: grammar-identification, new-latin, impersonal

Reading [*Naufragium*](https://la.wikisource.org/wiki/Colloquia_familiaria/Naufragium) by Erasmus (1523), I came across this sentence. I include the whole sentence for context, but I'm only asking about the part in bold:

> **Circumspicienti tandem venit in mentem de ima mali parte**: eam quoniam solus eximere non poteram, adscisco socium: huic ambo innixi committimus nos mari, sic ut ego dextrum cornu tenerem, ille laevum.

I take this to mean:

> **Looking around, it finally came into my mind—the lower part of the mast**: since I couldn't wrest it out myself, I enlist a partner: both of us supported by it, we commit ourselves to the sea like so: I would hold the right horn, he the left.

I got to wondering, what explains **circumspicienti**? Why not **circumspiciens**?

Ah, I see, because the speaker is not the subject of the sentence. He has put himself into an ablative absolute as a present participle. But then what *is* the subject of this sentence? Not the lower part of the mast: it's the object of **de**, hence ablative. **Venit** appears to be an impersonal verb here. Can you *do* that?

In four other places in the same story, Erasmus uses the expression *in mentem venit,* always with the thing or person coming to mind made explicitly the subject of *venit.*

Comment: "He has put himself into an ablative absolute as a present participle" -- immo dativus est.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Is it as if he had written _mihi circumspicienti_? Come to think of it, I don't think I've ever seen _mihi_ with an adjective.

Comment: Yes, unless he's Caesar  I do remember "mihi consuli designato, Catilina, insidiatus es" (Cic. In Catilinam 1,11), so there is that, at least. (Also *mihi ipsi* here and there, but I guess that doesn't count.)

Comment: @BenKovitz, consider this: *Cogitanti mihi saepenumero et memoria vetera repetenti perbeati fuisse* (https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16212/meaning-of-the-first-line-of-ciceros-de-oratore/16213)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Gratias respondenti ago! Legenti tandem in mentem venit de caso recto. (I am still surprised by both the flexibility and ambiguity of Latin grammar.)

Comment: @Ben Kovitz: Isn't "circumspicienti" ablative--by looking around, it finally came into my mind..."?

Comment: @tony That's what I thought until Sebastian Koppehel corrected me. The main form of the expression is _mihi tandem in mentem aliquid_, where _aliquid_ is the subject of the sentence. The dative indicates whose mind it came into. Erasmus has written _circumspicienti_ instead of _mihi_, leaving it to implication that the speaker is looking around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, Cicero himself uses *in mentem venire* impersonally, though with the genitive rather than *de*:

> cum hoc vereor et cupio tibi aliqua ex parte quod salva fide possim
> parcere, rursus immuto voluntatem meam; venit enim mihi in mentem oris
> tui.
>
> And as I am afraid of this, and as I wish to spare you in some degree,
> as far as I can, saving my duty to my client, I will again change my
> purpose. For the thoughts on your countenance present here occur to my
> mind. (trans C. D. Yonge)

Pro S. Roscio Amerino 95

I cannot offer any firm answer as to what licenses the use of this particular verb in this way. My best guess is that this construction, impersonal verb with a genitive complement, is employed with mental events that de-emphasize agent and emphasize experience. E.g., pudet, piget, taedet, paenitet. Of course, those verbs are all transitive, whereas venire here uses the dative to specify the experiencer.

Comment: Can you add anything about why it makes sense to use _venire_ impersonally? Can you do this with any verb at all?

Comment: @BenKovitz I cannot offer any firm answer as to what licenses the use of this particular verb in this way. My best guess is that this construction, impersonal verb with a genitive complement, is employed with mental events that de-emphasize agent and emphasize experience. E.g., pudet, piget, taedet, paenitet. Of course, those verbs are all transitive, whereas venire here uses the dative to specify the experiencer.

Comment: That sounds to me like a very good educated guess, at the very least. I took the liberty of copying it into your answer. It sheds some valuable light on why a fluent Latin speaker would find it reasonable to use _venit_ impersonally even if he hadn't encountered this construction before—exactly what I was hoping for in an answer. (Feel free to revert, of course.)

Answer (score 4):

According to [Pinkster (2015: 117)](https://books.google.es/books?id=Y05zCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=Pinkster%20mihi%20venit%20in%20mentem&source=bl&ots=hSjkFSk8by&sig=ACfU3U2XuJ-Jr1e7T-uG9pPaeSglZoFETA&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP8tHO1rjzAhUkyYUKHeo6DgQQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q=Pinkster%20mihi%20venit%20in%20mentem&f=false): "The expression *mihi venit in mentem* is used either as an impersonal expression, with the entity remembered or forgotten expressed in the genitive, or as a personal one. The latter construction is normal if that entity is a neuter pronoun or adjective, but nouns can be used as well. The verbs *memini* and *recordor* are used occasionally with the preposition *de*".

> Ecquidnam meminit **Mnesilochi**?
> ‘Does she remember Mnesilochus at all?’ (Pl. *Bac.* 206)

> Venit enim mihi **Platonis** in mentem.
> ‘I am reminded of Plato.’  (Cic. *Fin.* 5.2)

Some authors (e.g. [Baños (2019: 10)](https://eprints.ucm.es/id/eprint/62406/7/Ba%C3%B1os%20Ba%C3%B1os,%20Jos%C3%A9%20Miguel.%20Las%20construcciones%20con%20verbo%20soporte%20en%20lat%C3%ADn.pdf)) analyze the impersonal construction *mihi in mentem venire* as a sort of "lexical passive" of *meminisse*, which lacks a morphological passive. According to this Spanish latinist, "*in mentem (mihi) venire* (...) tiene, de nuevo, una justificación funcional evidente: ante la imposibilidad de una pasiva morfológica con *memini* (como tampoco la tenía *odi*, o los verbos deponentes biargumentales), (...) *mentem mihi venire* se acaba convirtiendo en su pasiva léxica, como ilustran los ejemplos paralelos [siguientes]":

> memini ego **istuc** (Plaut. *Capt.* 317)

> idem **istuc** mihi venit in mentem (Ter. *Heaut.* 889)

Finally, as for the OP's interesting example from Erasmus (*Circumspicienti tandem venit in mentem **de ima mali parte***), it could be the case that the (generalized) use of the prepositional phrase headed by *de* is an influence of Late Latin. For example, this [impersonal construction](http://www.javierelvira.es/impersonalidad.pdf) with this Prepositional Phrase is quite frequent in Old Spanish:

> Non te viene en miente en valençia **del Leon** (Cid, 66v)

> non me viene en miente **desos malos recabdos** (LBA, 742c)

The Latin impersonal construction *alicui in mentem venire de aliquo* is even still preserved in contemporary Italian (although the personal construction is more typical):

> Mi venne in mente **di te** ([source](https://books.google.es/books?id=c1EU30xQGMAC&pg=PA124&lpg=PA124&dq=%22Mi%20venne%20in%20mente%20di%20te%22&source=bl&ots=d7_Xjrr421&sig=ACfU3U1b5ZBwVZ71LkZdFQZbjZdPATsB9Q&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi00bLU58LzAhXiAmMBHV0XBTIQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22Mi%20venne%20in%20mente%20di%20te%22&f=false)). Cf. Lat. *{tui/de te} mihi in mentem venit*.

My hunch is that the genitive in this particular example/construction could not sound natural to Erasmus and he preferred using the Prep. Phrase "de+abl." instead. Similarly, it seems that this construction did not sound natural to Petrarch either, whereby he conjectured the insertion of (nominative) [***imago***](https://books.google.es/books?id=rdBrV5_rxCYC&pg=PA170&dq=Petrarch%20imago%20veniebat%20in%20mentem&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI6I7zjLnzAhWC8OAKHbGbA7YQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=Petrarch%20imago%20veniebat%20in%20mentem&f=false) to account for the genitive in the following example from Cicero, *Pro Sulla*, VI, 18-19: *sed cum mihi patriae, cum vestrorum periculorum, cum huius urbis, cum illorum delubrorum atque templorum, cum puerorum infantium, cum matronarum ac virginum veniebat in mentem,...*.

Linguistically speaking, what I think is interesting is that from this non-agentive collocation (*alicui in mentem venire*) there is no way to obtain an **impersonal** passive. Note that the [impersonal passive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impersonal_passive_voice) of *venire* would only be possible if and only if the verb is agentive (e.g. *ubi eo ventum est* ('when they arrived there', Caes. *BG*. 1.43.4)).

Comment: I'm glad this construction has received scholarly attention and isn't just my usual language learner's confusion! I took _de_ to invoke the notion of a topic (like "about" in English), i.e. Erasmus wasn't using _de_ as a generic or genitive preposition. Plausible?

Comment: @BenKovitz  My hunch is that the genitive in this particular example/construction could not sound natural to Erasmus and he preferred using the PP "de+abl." In this sense it is also interesting that, as you can see in the link below, Petrarch has been said to conjecture insertion of (nominative) _imago_ to account for the genitive in this example from Cicero, _Pro Sulla_, VI, 19 : _cum vestrorum periculorum, cum huius urbis, cum illorum delubrorum atque templorum, cum puerorum infantium, cum matronarum ac virginum veniebat in mentem_.

Comment: @BenKovitz See the comment in this link: https://books.google.es/books?id=rdBrV5_rxCYC&pg=PA170&dq=Petrarch+imago+veniebat+in+mentem&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI6I7zjLnzAhWC8OAKHbGbA7YQ6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=Petrarch%20imago%20veniebat%20in%20mentem&f=false

Comment: An implied _imago_ is certainly an interesting idea. It would even explain Erasmus's _de_. Here, though, is a deep theoretical question: couldn't each impersonal _in mentem venit_ result not from a rule or implied subject, but each person making an analogy with other impersonal verbs anew?

Comment: @BenKovitz Perhaps Petrarch did not consider the genitive in this construction as grammatically motivated, hence his conjecture of inserting _imago_ to justify this case. Linguistically speaking, what I think is interesting is that from this non-agentive collocation (_in mentem venire_) there is no way to obtain an impersonal passive. Note that the impersonal passive of _venire_ would only be possible if and only if the verb is agentive (e.g. _ubi eo ventum est_ ('when they arrived there', Caes. _BG._ 1.43.4)).  See the Latin section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impersonal_passive_voice